# JTable : how to align data in the center or how to set row background color alternate

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color, defaulttablemodel

How can I set the row background color in  `JTable` and also align the data to the center.The `JTable1` is dynamic. `JTable` uses `defaultTableModel` for setting the data. I want to if `i%==0` than background color is `#Color.GRAY` else `#Color.WHITE` I read about render class but can not understand about renderer class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class FacultyList extends JPanel {

    static DefaultTableModel dm;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane jsp_table;
    static Connection conn;
    static Statement stmt;
    static ResultSet rs;

    public FacultyList(Connection c) {
        conn = c;
        String col_name[] = {"S.No.", "Name", "Father Name", "College ID", 
            "Gender", "Date of Birth", "Branch", "Contact No."};
        dm = new DefaultTableModel(null, col_name);
        table = new JTable(dm);
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Goudy Old Style", Font.BOLD, 15));
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(125);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(125);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(225);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jsp_table = new JScrollPane(table);
        jsp_table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(975, 520));
        addRowTable();
        add(jsp_table);
    }

    public static void addRowTable() {
        try {
            int a = dm.getRowCount();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < a) {
                dm.removeRow(0);
                i++;
            }
            String fac = "Faculty";
            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NAME, FNAME, CLG_ID, GANDER, "
                    + "DOB, BRANCH, CONTACT FROM PROFILE "
                    + "where I_AM = '" + fac + "'");
            int count = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String s[] = new String[8];
                s[0] = "" + count;
                s[1] = rs.getString(1);
                s[2] = rs.getString(2);
                s[3] = rs.getString(3);
                s[4] = rs.getString(4);
                s[5] = rs.getString(5);
                s[6] = rs.getString(6);
                s[7] = "" + rs.getLong(7);
                count++;
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                } else {
                }
                dm.addRow(s);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please where did you read about Renderer - (I read about rander class but can not understand about rander class)

Comment: on this site or java oracle doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom renderer to do this. It can be done as follows :

```
 table1 = new JTable(){

public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer tcr, int row,
    int column) {
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(tcr, row, column);

    if (isRowSelected(row)) {

        c.setForeground(getSelectionForeground());
        c.setBackground(getSelectionBackground());

    } else {

        c.setForeground(getForeground());
        c.setBackground((row % 2 == 0) ? getBackground()
            : Color.lightGray);
    }

    int rendererWidth = c.getPreferredSize().width;
    TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth
        + getIntercellSpacing().width,
        tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));

DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
return c;
    }

  };;
```

Comment: why collection of prepareRenderer and DefaultTableCellRenderer, can be confortly done in one of them, could be very CPU intensive to combine two XxxRenderers for one JTable, Column, Cell ...

Answer (score 1):

> on this site or java oracle doc

- [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is just about painting, is statics painting based on settings in XxxTableCellRenderer, isn't interactive, is about painting illusion,
- painting in `XxxTableCellRenderer` is quite intesive and is invoked from all key and mouse events, methods implemented in rellated APIs
- it could be separate definition for `JTable` or separate class thats returns rulles, painting definitions for `JTable`s view
- `JDBC` isn't good place to set or define the Renderer, about add a new data from database to [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data),
- `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` could not be set for `JTable`, is snapshot from ResultSet, it hasn't any action back to database
- why is returns from `JDBC` restricted to `String s[] = new String[8];`, set [data typed correctly by override getColumnClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- set alignment in Renderer (data typed returns alingment by default), e,g, by cast to JLabel, then all methods implemented in [JLabels API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) can be used there
- by default there are used [prepareRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968%20getTableCellRendererComponent), [getTableCellRendererComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968%20getTableCellRendererComponent), both for whole `JTable`s view and many various attempts for `Renderer` applied just for the concrete Columns